# How to allow users to open page in another tab and not have to login again

Tags: angular

I am using Angular to create a web app. I am trying to implement a functionality that when a user logs into the app they can open another tab and not be prompt to log in again(Go straight to the home page). I currently save the users JWT token and Refresh token in local storage.

Comment: Save JWT in local storage and retrieve it when app start to check the exiting of login session.. It's not good enough. Please explain further?

Comment: If you refresh the original tab, does the user stay logged in..?

Comment: Thing keep in local storage is shared with every tab related to the same referral URL. So, if you make it right, you can retrieve data. Just do not clear the data when app start. check it exists, retrieve it, check it expires time. If it's ok.. you still have session.

Comment: Caveat is user still login, if they are not explicitly logout by clearing JWT in localstorage,ie. close tab without click logout. Actually, the best solution using both localStorage and sessionStorage.

Comment: @ChayneP.S. you can use localStorage or a secure cookie. then have a timeout on the server of if a token is X hours old it needs to be cleared. that way a user isn't logging in all the time, but you don't have infinite log in time

Comment: @rhavelka Timeout is not good enough in the case of sharing computers like in the library. There a chance that the user followed can have the token. But actually Cookie is perfect works for a between-tab sharing session but it needs server to handle Cookie instead of heders.